# Where to get the o3djs javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, o3d

I want to start messing around with o3d but I can't find where to download o3djs javascript libraries.  I downloaded the plugin from http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/ but I cannot find where to download the libraries from.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serge Meunier also posted them on the intro screen to his o3d tutorial blog, they are packaged nicely in this download: http://www.sergemeunier.com/blog/o3d-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can find them in the subversion repository. http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/o3d/samples/o3djs/